# Check Size of Included Library C++

Tags: c++, include, shared-libraries

Is there a way to check the size of a library? Specifically I am looking for the size of libcurl.

It's included in my program as follows:

```
#include <curl/curl.h>
```

Is there a way for me to determine what object '/curl/curl.h' links to and how big that object is?

There is a libcurl.so file in /usr/lib64.. Could this be what I'm looking for?

Thanks!

Comment: May I ask, why exactly you want to know the size? Because it is not indicative of the size of the compiled program.

Comment: I was asked the question in a review

Comment: Might have been a trick question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is rather strange question for a review.
There is no link between header file and library aside association in package manager. Header tells what objects it have to expect. Library contains those objects. It isn't and will not be linked to library in any way. You have to tell compiler which library to use and from where in command line.
Searching for curl.h in system cache indeed says thatcurl.h is part of libcurl*-dev packages. Library itself is libcurl* .so or .lib depending if its a static or dynamic one, at your choice.